# XMl Validation Error for xs:attribute ref

Tags: java, xml, xsd

My apologies if I am asking a repeated question. I did try to search online for a similar issue with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I

I am trying to validate an xml with an xsd. The xsd has multiple import statements to reference other xsd's.

I am getting this error for  any attributes which has ref

partial xml tag

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'bme:version' to a(n) 'attribute declaration' component.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAttributeTraverser.traverseLocal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDAbstractTraverser.traverseAttrsAndAttrGrps(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.processComplexContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseComplexTypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDComplexTypeTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getGlobalDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseNamedElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDElementTraverser.traverseGlobal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.traverseSchemas(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 0):

All `schemaLocation`'s should point to referenced xsd's. Make sure that schemaLocations are given and they are valid paths.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the error message means what it says: your schema contains an xs:attribute ref="X" where there is not attribute declaration named X. This could be because of a failure to import the schema or because the namespaces are wrong. But we can't debug your schema without seeing it.